# Java: fast way to get size of generated JSON in bytes

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I have some JSON data in an `InputStream` and I need to split it into parts no bigger than 5MB and upload the parts separately. I have a working solution (below) to do this, but getting the size of the generated JSON takes longer and longer as I iterate through the JSON nodes.

I tried getting the size of each node and adding it to a global "total" variable (which is pretty fast), but that doesn't take into account the commas that will separate all the nodes in the final generated JSON.
**Thought**: what if I do this way until the threshold and then remove nodes until the final generated JSON with all the commas is under the threshold?

I'm using the Jackson jars and would not like to use anything else just for this one little thing.

Here's the format of the input data:

```
[
    { "nodeData": 1 },
    { "nodeData": 2 },
    { "nodeData": 3 }
]
```

Here's my working Java code:

```
ObjectMapper jsonMapper = ...
JsonNode tree = jsonMapper.readTree(inputStream);
List<JsonNode> nodeParts = new ArrayList<JsonNode>();

if (tree != null) {
    for (Iterator<JsonNode> nodes = tree.elements(); nodes.hasNext();) {
        JsonNode node = nodes.next();

        nodeParts.add(node);

        // this takes longer and longer as the nodeParts List grows
        byte[] bytes = jsonMapper.writeValueAsBytes(nodeParts);

        if (bytes.length > UPLOAD_SIZE_BYTES_THRESHOLD) {
            bytes = null;
            // remove the one we just added that put it over the threshold
            nodeParts.remove(nodeParts.size() - 1);

            // upload nodeParts

            nodeParts.clear();
            nodeParts.add(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the parts have to be valid json?

Comment: @pablochan It assumes the original input data is already valid. I updated the question with the JSON format.

Comment: Can't you write JSON to any `OutputStream` implementation that just counts bytes written? For example, Guava CountingOutputStream - http://javadoc.scijava.org/Guava/com/google/common/io/CountingOutputStream.html.

Comment: @yegodm A CountingOutputStream still has to generate the JSON. And it's only a couple ms faster, and sometimes it's actually a couple ms slower -- with 5000 nodes.

Comment: OK, maybe you can try using Apache Commons `ThresholdingOutputStream` instead. It raises an event when the configured threshold of bytes is reached: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/ThresholdingOutputStream.html. It would likely to require serializing of a custom `Iterator` over the nodes capable of 1) stopping iteration when the stream signaled, 2) remembering and reporting the last written index, 3) being able to start iteration from the given index.

Comment: @Matt I was asking about the output. Does the output have to be valid json, aside from being below 5mb?

Comment: @pablochan yes - it will be uploaded to a server where it will be parsed as JSON